# fine tuning a goto bookmark libreoffice macro

Tags: libreoffice, bookmarks, uno, libreoffice-basic

I have a libreoffice macro to go to a certain bookmark ("qui")

```
sub vai_qui
ViewCursor = ThisComponent.CurrentController.getviewCursor()
Bookmark = ThisComponent.Bookmarks.getByName("qui").Anchor
ViewCursor.gotorange(Bookmark, False)
end sub
```

The problems are two:

1. this is a *libreoffice* macro, and so it runs also with Calc and Base, and I'd like to avoid error messages in Calc and Base;
2. With this macro the cursor go to the bookmark, but the *focus* of Writer is not on the cursor: I prefer to avoid this situation and have focus on cursor.

Thank you

Comment: Regarding the second problem: On running the subroutine via Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro, the cursor goes to the bookmark, and the view adjusts to show the location.  Is this not what you want?  If the behavior is different in your document, then how did you run it, and what ultimately takes the focus?

Comment: I don't know how or why, but is a fact that "the view *does not* adjusts to show the location", in a long document I don't get the focus on the cursor.

Comment: Please describe the conditions necessary to reproduce the second problem, known on stackoverflow as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  How long does the document need to be, and how did you run the macro, and what is in view after it runs?

Comment: 1) How long? More than ca. 149 lines (with 149 or less lines the focus is OK). 2) How I run the macro: autoopen (when document is open). 3) the focus is not on the cursor, it is on another portion of the document.

Comment: Solution: if I re-do the macro, all OK. So I duplicate, I repeat the instructions 2 times, and so it works!

Answer (score 0):

As you have been told on [LibreOffice forum](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/130411/writer-macro-to-go-to-a-bookmark/)***:

- avoid calling the macro, if you don't have a Writer document
- check for the document type

  ```
  If NOT ThisComponent.supportsService("com.sun.star.text.TextDocument" ) Then
     Exit Sub  
  End If
  ```
- check for bookmarks existence

  ```
  oBookmarks = ThisComponent.getBookmarks()  
  If NOT oBookmarks.hasByName("qui") Then
  ```

*** Cross-posting a question without any reference to other forums you asked for help is offending to the volunteers who spend their free time to help.

Comment: While I agree about cross-posting, that part should be a comment added to the question.  Answers should [just be answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17449), not critiques of the question.

Comment: Thank you, Ngulam: your answer solve the first problem. Remain now the second one.

Comment: The solution of ngulam now does not work properly with the new release of LibreOffice (Version: 5.4.1.2 Build ID: 1:5.4.1-0ubuntu1 - CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 4.13; UI render: default; VCL: kde4; Locale: it-IT (en_US.UTF-8); Calc: group). I get an error message: "BASIC runtime error. Property or method not found: supportsService" Could you help me?