# autoopen macro in LibreBase, after upgrade to last Kubuntu

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-base

With the advice I received in *[fine tuning a goto bookmark libreoffice macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204381/fine-tuning-a-goto-bookmark-libreoffice-macro)* and [here too](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/130411/writer-macro-to-go-to-a-bookmark/), I had successfully created a macro that in LibreWriter went to the last point where the cursor was at the end.

After upgrading from Kyubuntu 17.04 to Kubuntu 17.10, with the new version of LibreOffice I get an error message, not in Writer, not in Calc, but **in Base**:

> BASIC runtime error. Property or method not found: supportsService

and is highlighted the line `If NOT thisComponent.supportsService (" com.sun.star.text.TextDocument ") Then`. Apparently `supportsService` is not recognized in LibreBase.

I refer to the whole macro:

```
sub vai_qui
    If NOT ThisComponent.supportsService ("com.sun.star.text.TextDocument") Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    oBookmarks = ThisComponent.getBookmarks ()
    If NOT oBookmarks.hasByName ("here") Then
        Exit Sub
    End If


    ViewCursor = ThisComponent.CurrentController.getviewCursor ()
    Bookmark = ThisComponent.Bookmarks.getByName ("here") .Anchor
    ViewCursor.gotorange (Bookmark, False)

    ViewCursor = ThisComponent.CurrentController.getviewCursor ()
    Bookmark = ThisComponent.Bookmarks.getByName ("here") .Anchor
    ViewCursor.gotorange (Bookmark, False)
end sub
```

Comment: It is not possible set a macro (the problem is only in **base**) not "not writer document" but "base document"?

Comment: With LibreOffice 6 this bug is fixed

Answer (score 0):

"BASIC runtime error."

This is not a BASE error, it's a BASIC error.  Two very different things.  BASE is the database component of LO.  BASIC is a programming language that can be used to automate LO components in general, e.g. it works with Writer, Calc, Draw, Base, ...

Comment: I know: but, the solution?